# clicking checkbox using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox

I have a little task of scraping data from https://www.carecredit.com/doctor-locator/ .
I am unable to perform checkbox tick using my script.

I am doing

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.carecredit.com/doctor-locator/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='dl-
             profession']/option[@value='9']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='specialty-106']").click()
```

and getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='specialty-106']").click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.46.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 70, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.46.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 404, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.46.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 195, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.46.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 170, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="checkbox" id="specialty-106" name="Specialty[]" value="106"> is not clickable at point (281, 554). Other element would receive the click: <label for="specialty-106"></label>
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86_64)
```

Comment: Is there actually a line break in your xpath string? When I try your xpath on that page, it seems to work as long as there is no space between `dl-` and `profession`.

Comment: Instead of thanks, you should have included a question in your post. I removed the thanks, but wasn't sure if you wanted as question "If I switch to using perl, will selenium have the same problem?" or if you wanted to ask something else. So I leave it to you to come up with an appropriate interrogative sentence, edit your post and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

This code block will open the URL `https://www.carecredit.com/doctor-locator`, click on `Profession` Dropdown, select `Weight Loss` and finally select the checkbox `Weight Loss Surgery`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r"C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.carecredit.com/doctor-locator/')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('dl-profession'))
select.select_by_value("9")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='specialty-106']//following::label[1]")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='specialty-106']//following::label[1]").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback contains a very clear explanation of what's wrong.

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element  is
>   not clickable at point (281, 554). Other element would receive the
>   click:

You might have to add a delay between your two clicks, to wait for the DOM to update so that the element is clickable.

Comment: there is actually no space between dl- and profession but still it dosn't work at my end.I have used implicit wait of 3 seconds but it doesn't work.

Comment: I did try wait by doing  myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'specialty-106')))
but still not able to click.